# What's a good 2D animation program (an alternative for e.g. Flash CS)?

Tags: software-recommendation, flash, animations

I don't mean the flash player here, I'm talking about the flash program that I can make animations with. Like Adobe Flash CS (formerly known as Macromedia flash). Is there a program on linux that I can make animations? I want to make a movie like animator vs animation. I used easy gif animator on windows lol it was a bit harder than flash but I'm on linux and I'd like to know what it has to offer. Worse case scenario, what gif animators are there on linux.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some alternatives for Flash are:

1. Pencil (available in the Software Centre)
2. [Synfig](http://synfig.org/) (available in the Software Centre on 16.04)

Both may not be as powerful as Flash, but they may get your work done.

Answer (score 10):

[Synfig](http://www.synfig.org/) is probably what you are looking for.

The software's main focus is vector animation but it's able to do animated gif's as well. I'm reasonably certain it's the closest thing to Flash you're going to find on Linux (as of this typing).

Comment: Sorry Chakra, I think you finished your reply just as I started mine. Either way, I up-voted yours. I think I'll delete this unless anyone has any objections.

Comment: You posted a valid answer which others have voted for suggesting you have added value here. You should not feel the need to delete an answer to avoid treading on toes.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/) (which has notoriously slow development) and Synfig, Ktoon was recently resurrected as [Tupi](http://www.maefloresta.com/portal/) and is being actively developed as of writing this.

It has a more familiar interface for animation and only uses a single window, unlike Synfig

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't seen a viable flash creating application for Linux.  Gimp has animated GIF support where you create each frame as a layer and in the Filters option you can choose the delay of each layer which then gives an animation.  The only other option I can see is to either try and use Wine or a Virtual Machine to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't sell those versions of flash, you can install Wine, and install the software that way. But, Wine does take alot of space, and it needs yu to manually configure its registery.

Answer (score 0):

http://wideo.co is an excellent free tool to create 2d animation videos. You can upload your videos to youtube

Comment: it's only free for videos [up to 30 seconds length](https://wideo.co/en/payments/pricing/default-3?source=footer).