# How I create animation like Flash

Tags: installation, flash

I need to do the small animations in Ubuntu 12.04 Please let me know **what type of animation software are available for Ubuntu 12.04?**

If I can install the **Adobe Flash Professional** to my Ubuntu 12.04 is better.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Flash Professional is only for Windows platform. But there is a number of [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-flash/). Please try one of them.

Comment: From that link, [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/) deserves a try

Comment: Related (and maybe we should've duped to this instead): [How do I author Adobe Flash movies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/60404/22949) (if you mean Shockwave Flash web content) or [What's a good 2D animation program (an alternative for e.g. Flash CS)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/8611/22949) (if you mean professional general animation creation software)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from trying to run Adobe's Flash Professional under the WINE environment and hoping it works OK, here are a few alternatives to use:

[Open Laszlo](http://www.openlaszlo.org) and also **Ktoon** which is available in the *Software Center*, might be able to help to create our animation...